# Why has AirPlay to Apple TV stopped working from 3rd-party apps?

Tags: appletv, airplay

I have been using AirPlay to stream stuff to my Apple TV for months, and it's been great. In the last week or so it stopped working for 3rd-party apps.

- I use [Radium](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/radium/id413215890?mt=12&ls=1) on my Mac. This used to work fine but now when I unmute Apple TV it mutes itself again as soon as it starts to play.
- I use the [Digitally Imported](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/digitally-imported-radio/id375242617) app on my iPhone. I used to be able to stream this to Apple TV but now when I choose it it stops playing.

In both cases Apple TV shows up as a potential output device, and disappears and reappears as it should when I switch AirPlay off and on again on my Apple TV. I've tried 2 different routers and both wired and wireless connections. There is nothing relevant in the Console logs on my Mac that I can see.

The odd thing is that iTunes on my Mac can still play to it, and AirPlay mirroring works fine too, so it does seem to only affect 3rd-party applications.

How do I fix this?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I am having the same issue. I am not sure if it came with the last Mountain Lion update. It was working the other day. listening to music on Saturday 22/09/12. Then video on TV and music on the mac. Selected audio settings . did so on advice of a website. every time i select my AppleTV it keeps bouncing off - unselectable. upgraded the Apple Tv but that did not help.

Comment: Thanks.  Strangely enough that is all I had.  It just stopped working.  So I restarted the laptop in a Windows fixing sort of style and lo and behold, the Airplay is back and allowing audio to the TV.  Fixed.

Comment: Restarting everything didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent 5.1 software update to Apple TV seems to have fixed it.